# Drupal vs Some Other CMS

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I'm going to be moving my website to a CMS in the coming months I'd I need some help on choosing an appropriate CMS. Many of the websites I've seen tend to say "use Drupal, hands down". However, my website truly doesn't have a need for commenting or community features. Its pages will need to be modified occasionally, but not extensively. My website will also consist of many programs, each with their own sub-pages and menus.

There are probably 25 people that will need access to the content on my website and will need the ability to update it.

I do like the idea of being able to tag and categorize the content, and the modular aspect of Drupal but is it really right for my website? If not, which CMS may fit my needs better?

Comment: Sounds like you do need community features!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Drupal. The thing about Drupal is that you start out very small and add on as you need things. There is a ton of documentation, it is well coded, always being expanded on, good forum support, and free. It's the easiest to install, most problem free, and most maintainable CMS system I've seen so far.

You can turn Drupal commenting off with the press of a button, and if/when you decide to add onto your website, perhaps you want an ad rotator, more extensive user permissions, etc, etc, it is all already developed for you and ready to go.

I am not sure if Wordpress supports multiple users on a site.

The smallest you can go for a CMS is something like 10kCMS or the more popular TinyMCE

Comment: @Vecta regarding your earlier comment about the large inherited website, a tiny CMS probably won't end well with you. However, with Drupal, you will have to convert that massive thing into Drupal - I don't know how well that will go for you, I haven't done it myself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Drupal would be an excellent solution to your company's needs. I used to recommend WordPress for smaller, single-blog type sites, but now, even for those, I recommend Drupal because you can start small and scale up as your needs grow. It has a very dedicated community and there is a module for just about any need you may have.

Answer (score 0):

If it is something small I will go with WordPress as it is easily themed and extensible. There are a lot of community plugins and support. Their documentation is also fairly simple as they don't have a thousand of functions and stuff you need to remember and understand. With some creativity the basic functionality of WordPress is sufficient to solve almost all problems that might arise in small to mid-size website.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, my company's website is massive, consisting of well over 5,000 pages. I inherited this website from the past web designers who neglected it for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I also like Drupal, but you may consider Umbraco as well. http://umbraco.org/ I'd use Umbraco over Drupal if your team is stronger in .Net than PHP.  (Really, I think that's a larger concern - what are your organization's strengths? Play to suit them.  You are making a decision that will pave the way for many developers besides yourself, and business decisions of your company.)   Both are extendable and open source so you can write your own modules/components to customize.  It may be cleaner to import into Drupal tables than Umbraco, since it goes down to xslt files. (EDIT: This looks to be no longer the case in the new version - http://umbracohosting.com/umbraco-4---get-excited/one-cms-any-database)  From a front end dev perspective, both offer great control of the final output.

From working on legacy stuff a lot, you may end up hiring interns to do the gruntwork.  There's bound to be tons of inline tables and all sorts of un-reusable code in there, it may be easier to scrape the content manually and start w/clean markup for the content portions.

Comment: Screen-Scraping is easiest to convert to Umbraco? That's hideous! I'd hate to be the webmaster.

Comment: Screen scraping is not the best way to import to Umbraco at all.  Utter nonsense.

Developers would use the api and non devs can just use cmsimport an umbraco package.